# AWS credentials from 'Single Sign On' expire too frequently - how can I get credentials with a longer lifetime?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We automate various maintenance tasks using the AWS API. Frequently calls to AWS services fail with:

```
The security token included in the request is expired
```

I know I can visit AWS and get updated credentials:

[image]

But **is there a way to get credentials with a longer lifetime**? In order to properly automate our AWS tasks we need to not need to log in manually and fetch credentials every week or so.

Comment: It appears that you are using temporary credentials provided by the AWS Security Token Service. Are you assuming a role? Or are you using Vocareum? Please tell us more about your situation.

Comment: You will need to chat with the AWS Admins in your company. It is 100% possible to provide permanent credentials, but you will need to find out why they are requiring you to obtain access through that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots above are from AWS Single Sign-On - the keys presented are short lived. If you create an Access Key for an IAM User, then they are **permanent credentials**:

- In the IAM Console, create an IAM User
- Go to the **Security Credentials** tab
- Click **Create access key**

An IAM User can have up to two active Access Keys, which is handy for rotating credentials. In addition, the keys can be limited to certain services on AWS (eg, RDS only).

Comment: This is very ill advise as the OP asked for a longer lifetime, and permanent IAM Users are an effective way to short-circuit the **additional security** of SSO. You can for example skip the authenticator of a MFA approach that way.